# Laravel : how to check the check-box if it's value is exist in a array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have an services in an `array`, and I have a list of `checkbox` which have the same values in this `array` no I need to make each `checkbox` to be `checked` if it's in the `array`

here is my Blade code

```
{{ Form::checkbox('pro_serves[]', 'pool', null) }} Pool <br/>
{{ Form::checkbox('pro_serves[]', 'gym', null) }} Gym <br/>
{{ Form::checkbox('pro_serves[]', 'maintenance', null) }} Maintenance <br/>
{{ Form::checkbox('pro_serves[]', 'dish', null) }} Dish <br/>
{{ Form::checkbox('pro_serves[]', 'kidsArea', null) }} KidsArea <br/>
{{ Form::checkbox('pro_serves[]', 'parking', null) }} Parking
```

and here is my Controller

```
public function editProject($id)
    {
        $proId = Projects::findOrFail($id);
        $proImg = ProjectsImages::where('image_id', $id)->get();
        $proPln = ProjectsPlans::where('image_id', $id)->get();
        $services = $proId->pro_serves;
        $service = explode(',', $services);

        return View::make('admin.manageProject.editProject', compact('proId', 'proImg', 'proPln', 'service'));
    }
```

now as you see I am sending the `service` as an `array` to the `view` how can I implement this?
and I welcome any new ideas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're either using an old version of laravel, or the `laravelcollection/html` package, you merely need to pass a third argument.

This is a checked checkbox:

```
{{ Form::checkbox('pro_servers[]', 'pool', true) }}
```

So, to have it checked if the value is in the array you can simply do:

```
{{ Form::checkbox('pro_servers[]', 'pool', in_array('pool', $theArray)) }}
```

There you go.

This is actually covered in the documentation, which I always recommend taking a look at before posting on SO.